# Computing line integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Can someone please help me solve the following line integral? I have difficulty with heuristics of these kinds of problems, any help would be appreciated.

Let $F(x,y)=(x^2,-y),$  $C$ is the graph of $y=e^x$ from $(2,e^2)\to (0,1)$. Compute $\int_CF$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function $e^x$ does not map $(2, e^2)$  to $(0,1)$. There is something wrong here.

Comment: @Thomas no there is no typo. this is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is something wrong with the domains or targets, you seem to be looking at the curve $x\mapsto (x,y(x))= (x, e^x)$ which has tangent $v(x)=(1, e^x)$ so you have to integrate (with $G(x)= F(x, y(x)) = (x^2, -e^x)^T$)

$$\int \langle G(x), v(x)\rangle dx = \int \langle (x^2, -e^{x})^T, (1, e^x)^T\rangle dx = \int x^2 -e^{2x}dx$$

with the bounds you were given (which should not be too difficult)